# how to point out a location with maxval in a vector

Tags: r

A question on pointing out a location with maximum value in a vector.

For say, i have a vector with 10 numbers,

```
x <- rnorm(10,0,1) [1]  1.1353978 -1.4852905 -0.1216639  0.1943784 -1.0968827  1.1051740  0.4738447 -0.6507678  0.2599902 -0.1355366


maxval <- max(x)
loc_val <- ? in this case, it should point out 1st element. loc_val <- 1
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`which.max()` is your friend. See `?which.max` and the example below:

```
R> set.seed(2)
R> x <- rnorm(10)
R> x
 [1] -0.89691455  0.18484918  1.58784533 -1.13037567 -0.08025176  0.13242028
 [7]  0.70795473 -0.23969802  1.98447394 -0.13878701
R> max(x)
[1] 1.984474
R> which.max(x)
[1] 9
```

Comment: at gavin, wondering as well how to get all loc values of the pre-sorted vector after sorting, i am trying x1_sort <- sort(x, decreasing=T) loc_vals_pre_sort <- ???

Comment: @verda not sure I fully grep what you want. Ask a new Q with example input, code you use and expected output for the bit you don't know how to do. I'll take a look, as will others I'm sure.